# Possibilities of a navigation bar design

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

[image: expected design]
Is it possible to design a navigation bar like the one seen above? It is not the standard design for the navigation bar tho. So wondering what are the chances that it can be done? The buttons are of no issues. Its part where the buttons protrude out from the navigation bar that seems to be challenging. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

The easiest way might be to just use a UIImageView for the toolbar background and place UIButtons above it for the buttons. Hook up the buttons to IBActions for popping the navigation controller or whatever else you might want them to do.